# How can I change rectangle button background image when I click on button in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Normally, I can change rectangle's background image to this below code:

```
ImageBrush brush1 = new ImageBrush();
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName) + "\\images\\image\\MessageEtkileşim.png"));
brush1.ImageSource = image;
renctangle.Fill = brush1;
```

But when I make button to renctangle I dont change button background.I tried below code but didn't work.

```
ImageBrush brush1 = new ImageBrush();
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName) + "\\images\\image\\MessageEtkileşim.png"));
brush1.ImageSource = image;
renctanglebutton.Background = brush1;
```

Comment: I'm assuming that by "didn't work" you mean it compiled and ran, but didn't do what you expected?
Presumable 'renctangle' and 'renctanglebutton' are actually the correct object names (instead of 'rectangle' and 'rectanglebutton')?

Comment: The rectanglebutton background didn't change.The rectanglebutton is my button's name.

rectangle ==> make into control ==> rectanglebutton.

Comment: could you show the code where you 'make the rectange into a control'?

Comment: u need to write a template for the button and bind the background of the rectangle in that template to the image property

Comment: Yes I write template but I can't call template'elements.